# cairocffi install failed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, requirements.txt, weasyprint

I am running `pip freeze` on a python project, it shows string VERSION other than numberical version and it fails the package installation, the warning message is:

> weasyprint 43 has requirement cairocffi>=0.9.0, but you'll have cairocffi file-.cairocffi-VERSION which is incompatible.

```
cairocffi===file-.cairocffi-VERSION
```

cairoccffi is a dependency of Weasyprint which i use in my project and weasypring version is correct:

```
WeasyPrint==43
```

I tried using `pipreqs` generates requirements.txt, it didn't show cairocffi package but the package installation fails with the same error.

I checked site-packages folder, it contains

```
cairocffi-file_.cairocffi_VERSION.dist-info/
```

which cause the issue.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue pops up if you have an older version of [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) installed. You can upgrade to the latest version with `pip install --upgrade setuptools`.

Then, reinstall without using the cache: `pip install --no-cache-dir cairocffi`.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of cairocffi(1.0.2) seems to have a problem with versioning.

```
>>pip3 show cairocffi
Name: cairocffi
**Version: file-.cairocffi-VERSION**
Summary: cffi-based cairo bindings for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Kozea/cairocffi
Author: Simon Sapin
Author-email: community@kozea.fr
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: cffi, setuptools
```

Uninstall this version and try to install version (1.0.1)

```
pip3 install cairocffi==1.0.1
```

```
>>pip3 show cairocffi
Name: cairocffi
Version: 1.0.1
Summary: cffi-based cairo bindings for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Kozea/cairocffi
Author: Simon Sapin
Author-email: community@kozea.fr
License: BSD
Location: /home/one/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: cffi
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that following the Linux install instructions from this site is what finally cleared up the issue for me.  I am running Ubuntu on WSL (Windows Services for Linux).

[weasyprint install doc](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html)